# GridView Elements changes their place(Android)

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a problem. When i scrolling my *gridView* *Images* changes their place. *GetView* code. Thx

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);

    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Element layout. It was first listView. Im using list adapter for gridView. 
***list_row_layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff34495e"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="-24dp"
android:paddingBottom="-24dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView and GridView recycle items when they are not visible anymore, so if your ImageView isn't being set with the image correctly you will have problems.

The only place you set the image in "holder.imageView" is apparently inside ImageDownloaderTask, so you must have a problem inside that class.
Or it isn't setting holder.imageView correctly or it is taking too long to download the image and to replace the older one.

Try this:

```
if (holder.imageView != null) {
  holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
  new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
}
```

This won't make things right but you will see more clearly when the ImageDownloaderTask class is working and when it is not.

Comment: I replaced it with Picasso Plugin. Working better. But not as i want:)

Answer (score 0):

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.icontext, null);
    }else{
        v = convertView;
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
    tv.setText(providers[position]);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: What is a "cu" and id.download?

Comment: I think ur holder stores old data

Comment: grid recycle invisible items.  I don't know what i should do.